# Make a `where` in Ionic with Firebase 3

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I have my DB in Firebase but I want to do a `WHERE`, as a login (i.e. if I enter the user and the password, it brings me the user's corresponding data).

> This is my DB in firebase:

[image]

An example:

When I send the email and telefono to tb01_usuario bring me the corresponding data:

Currently I am doing it only with the ID that is similar to the field telephone, but I need to do it with the two fields that are inside each record, I hope they understand me

```
verifica_usuario(telefono: string,email : email ) {

    email = email;
    telefono = telefono;

    let promesa = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      //this.items = afDB.list('/cuisines');
      this.af.list('/tb01_usuario/' + telefono + email )
        .subscribe(data => {
          if (data.length === 0) {
            //clave no es correcta
            resolve(false);
          } else {
            //clave correcta
            this.telefono = telefono;
            this.guardar_storage();
            resolve(true);
          }
        });
    })
      .catch(error => console.log("ERROR en promesa Service: " + JSON.stringify(error)));

    return promesa;
  }
```

Comment: This question is pretty unclear - are you asking how to perform a query in Firebase based on two child nodes; name and telephone? i.e. where name = 'some name' *and* telephone = 'some telephone'?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that directly in Firebase.

As per [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/)

> The Realtime Database API is designed to only allow operations that can be executed quickly.

You should [structure your data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data) in a way that you can easily fetch what you need.

Comment: Make a `where` in Ionic 3 with FireBase

Comment: Telling the OP to 'read the docs' really isn't an answer. How about providing an asnwer (solution) to the question via a code and Firebase structure example?

Answer (score 0):

What you might want to use is either redundant nodes (similar to what MarianoCordoba mentioned), which is replicating data in a way that makes it easier to access what you need, or `indexOn` ([documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data)) and `orderByChild([CHILD_NODE]).equalTo([QUERY])` ([documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data)). Note that you can also use `orderByKey()` and `orderByValue()`, which allow you to filter/sort your data (which is what I'm assuming you mean by using `WHERE` in Firebase).